# Как заменить значение data атрибута в ссылке?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет. Хочу заменить значение атрибута 'data-quantity' в ссылке. 
Как это сделать? через val, html, text не получается..

```js
var number = 3;
$('a').attr('data-quantity').val(number);
```

```html
<a href="#" data-quantity="1">Купить</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var number = 3;
$('a').data('quantity', number);
```

Подробнее тут: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: И не забудьте про селекторы (классы или что там у вас, id?) !
Предыдущие ответы поменяют дата-аттрибут у всех элементов с указанным дата-аттрибутом, как бы это каламбурно не звучало))!!!

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
var number = 3;    
$('a').attr('data-quantity', number);
```

Comment: единственное, что плохо - меняется js, но html остается изначальный - кабы при перезагрузке этот параметр не сбрасывался...

Comment: Меняйте параметр на сервере, чтобы при перезагрузке он принимал нужное значение. 2й вариант: храните данные в localStorage, откуда забирайте их js при загрузке/перезагрузке страницы в браузер.

Answer (score 0):

вот так: `$('a').data('quantity',number);`